# Interfaces and classes

Tags: php, class, interface, polymorphism

I wonder if is a possible in PHP that code:

```
interfaces In{}
class Cl implements In{}
```

And:

```
In $var = new Cl();
```

Comment: May I ask what the actual question is....?

Answer (score 0):

Interface can be used like this.

```
// Declare the interface 'iTemplate'
interface iTemplate
{
    public function setVariable($name, $var);
    public function getHtml($template);
}

// Implement the interface
class Template implements iTemplate
{
    private $vars = array();

    public function setVariable($name, $var)
    {
        $this->vars[$name] = $var;
    }

    public function getHtml($template)
    {
        foreach($this->vars as $name => $value) {
            $template = str_replace('{' . $name . '}', $value, $template);
        }

        return $template;
    }
}
```

reference : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: I know, but i ask about create class instance from interface, I ask about using polymorphism like in java or C#

Comment: @Piotr Stachurski : Oh ! Your question wasn't clear. I edited my answer to provide you a polymorphism example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can :

```
<?php
interface In{}
class Cl implements In{}

$var = new Cl();
var_dump($var);
echo ($var instanceof In)?'Yes $var implements In':'No $var doesn\'t implements In';
echo "\n";
echo ($var instanceof Cl)?'Yes $var implements Cl':'No $var doesn\'t implements Cl';
```

Will output :

> object(Cl)#1 (0) {}
>
> Yes $var implements In
>
> Yes $var implements Cl

[Here is a sandbox to try yourself](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d9af07bedd18a90ca2fdda7f8a895bd14fa29232)

[Here is the documentation about interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php)

And if you're asking about Polymorphism, you could use Traits :

```
<?php
trait Hello {
    public function sayHello() {
        echo 'Hello ';
    }
}

trait World {
    public function sayWorld() {
        echo 'World';
    }
}

class MyHelloWorld {
    use Hello, World;
    public function sayExclamationMark() {
        echo '!';
    }
}

$o = new MyHelloWorld();
$o->sayHello();
$o->sayWorld();
$o->sayExclamationMark();
?>
```

[Here is a sandbox to test it](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/25d9c341e2b509075f29dc91be22512f2b75d3c3)

[Here is the documentation about traits](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.traits.php)

Comment: Yes of course, I still think in java or C# way, PHP don't have a variable type declaration. Thanks for answer.